# Vandermonde-like sum

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I know a Vandermonde's identity as

$$ \sum_{i=0}^c {a \choose i} {b \choose c-i} = {a+b \choose c} $$
$$ a, b, c \in \mathbb{N} $$

I am looking for a way to simplify these expressions:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^c {a \choose i} {b \choose c-i}(-1)^i\tag{1} $$
$$\sum_{i=x_1}^{x_2} {a \choose i} {b \choose c-i}(-1)^i\quad (x_1\ge 0,\; x_2\le a).\tag{2} $$

Comment: You might want to look at generating functions. Again, most combinatorial identities may be solved by the [Snake Oil](http://www.imocompendium.com/database/index.php?options=357&lmm=0) method.

Answer (score 2):

Except for trivial cases (if you sum just one term in your second expression, say), your sums do not admit a simple closed formula like the Vandermonde identity. More precisely, you can find a recurrence relation for your expression and use Petkovšek's algorithm to prove that it does not admit a hypergeometric solution.

Comment: In particular, let $f(c)$ denote the sum in $(1)$, then Maxima's `Zeilberger` function finds the recurrence $(c+2)f(c+2)=(c-b-a)f(c)+(b-a)f(c+1)$, and applying `solve_rec` to this returns `false` which implies that no hypergeometric solution exists.

Comment: Reference: [Petkovšek, Wilf, Zeilberger (1997): $A=B$](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.pdf)